# How to detect the color of an image using AS3 and adobe air?

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, colors, air

I'm having a hard time finding any data on how to detect the color of an image taken from a phone's camera using adobe air. The idea is that the user takes an image and then the app (that uses this code) detects the color of the item the user has photographed by placing a cursor on top of it.
So does someone please tell me how is this attainable in adobe air and action script 3.
many thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Is the image filled with solid color?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getPixel or getPixel32 from BitmapData() [enter link description here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel%28%29)

Than you can convert it to HEX if you wish.